# How to fix SVG image "drunk" behaviour in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, svg

everytime I try to use SVG images on my website something goes terribly wrong in only some browsers or only at some screen widths. I defaulted to giving up and using PNG instead, but today I decided to seek help.

I wanted to use a newly added logo on the checkout page. I created the logo in Affinity Designer and exported it to SVG.

It looks perfect on my Mac OS in: Brave, Chrome, Firefox and Safari at all screen widths.

It looks like the browser is drunk on mobile browsers: Brave, Chrome and Tor Browser.

That's how it looks like on desktop:

[image: logo on desktop]

And that's how it looks on mobile (gap between "T" and "i", rounded dot above "i", basically it's a different font!):

[image]

The SVG file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzVsq-xTyIxQemfnus1JLtozyZocDmtG/view?usp=sharing

Html (using bootstrap 4.4.1):

```
<div class="container my-5 text-center">
    <img src="/static/logo_BETiS_hotline.svg" height="38" alt="BETiS hotline">
</div>
```

I think the common denominator might be Affinity Designer, but it seems to be too established of a software to allow such glaring errors.

Before with a similar logo I had the issue where it would completely disappear only on specific viewport width range and only on my 24" 1920x1080 monitor. At the same viewport width on Macbook screen it was visible...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the culprit! Affinity Designer is to blame. During SVG export you can choose this option:

[image]

They set the default to export it as a font to save on size, but it's such a stupid default if it ends up breaking on half of the devices...